# Como verificar caso um select é nulo

Tags: php, json, pdo, select

Gente, possuo este código que puxa info do server

```
try {
    $conecta  = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$banco", $usuario, $senha);
    $consulta = $conecta->prepare('SELECT * FROM tb02_cardapiosem WHERE tb02_diasemana=' . $data);
    $consulta->execute(array());
    $resultadoDaConsulta = $consulta->fetchAll();

    $StringJson = "[";

    if (count($resultadoDaConsulta)) {
        foreach ($resultadoDaConsulta as $registro) {

            if ($StringJson != "[") {
                $StringJson .= ",";
            }
            $StringJson .= '{"tb02_lanchedia":"' . $registro[tb02_lanchedia] . '",';
            $StringJson .= '"tb02_almoco":"' . $registro[tb02_almoco] . '",';
            $StringJson .= '"tb02_cafe":"' . $registro[tb02_cafe] . '",';
            $StringJson .= '"tb02_lanchenoite":"' . $registro[tb02_lanchenoite] . '",';
            $StringJson .= '"tb02_diasemana":"' . $registro[tb02_diasemana] . '"}';

        }
        echo $StringJson . "]"; // Exibe o vettor JSON
    }   
}   
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage(); // opcional, apenas para teste
}
```

Depois, tenho este código que joga as informações encontradas numa div

```
function ConectaServidor(response) {
    var dados = JSON.parse(response); //faz a conversão do texto da WEB para JSON
    var i;
    var conteudo = "";
    var conteudo2 = "";
    var conteudo3 = "";
    var conteudo4 = "";
    for (i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) //dados.length retorna o tamanho do vetor.
    {
        conteudo += dados[i].tb02_cafe;
        conteudo2 += dados[i].tb02_lanchedia;
        conteudo3 += dados[i].tb02_almoco;
        conteudo4 += dados[i].tb02_lanchenoite;
    }

    document.getElementById("cafe1").innerHTML = conteudo;
    document.getElementById("lanche1").innerHTML = conteudo2;
    document.getElementById("almoco1").innerHTML = conteudo3;
    document.getElementById("lanchen1").innerHTML = conteudo4;
}
```

Porém não são todas as datas que estão cadastradas e gostaria que quando uma data não fosse encontrada, ele colocasse o innerHTML das Div's como "Não há registro!". Como fazer?

Comment: Pergunta: Por quê não utiliza a função [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) para converter seu *array* para JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gente, resolvi com um simples else. Vejam e comparem com o código anterior:

```
    try {
$conecta  = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$banco", $usuario, $senha);
$consulta = $conecta->prepare('SELECT * FROM tb02_cardapiosem WHERE tb02_diasemana=' . $data);
$consulta->execute(array());
$resultadoDaConsulta = $consulta->fetchAll();

$StringJson = "[";

if (count($resultadoDaConsulta)) {
    foreach ($resultadoDaConsulta as $registro) {

        if ($StringJson != "[") {
            $StringJson .= ",";
        }
        $StringJson .= '{"tb02_lanchedia":"' . $registro[tb02_lanchedia] . '",';
        $StringJson .= '"tb02_almoco":"' . $registro[tb02_almoco] . '",';
        $StringJson .= '"tb02_cafe":"' . $registro[tb02_cafe] . '",';
        $StringJson .= '"tb02_lanchenoite":"' . $registro[tb02_lanchenoite] . '",';
        $StringJson .= '"tb02_diasemana":"' . $registro[tb02_diasemana] . '"}';

    }
    echo $StringJson . "]"; // Exibe o vettor JSON
}else{
        echo $StringJson = '["Não há dados!"]';
    }
}       
   catch (PDOException $e) {
       echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage(); // opcional, apenas para teste
     }
```

Aí no meu javascript:

```
    function ConectaServidor(response) {
    var dados = JSON.parse(response);
    if(dados=="Não há dados!"){
        document.getElementById("cafe1").innerHTML = dados;
        document.getElementById("lanche1").innerHTML = dados;
        document.getElementById("almoco1").innerHTML = dados;
        document.getElementById("lanchen1").innerHTML = dados;
    }else{
    var i;
    var conteudo = "";
    var conteudo2 = "";
    var conteudo3 = "";
    var conteudo4 = "";
    for (i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) //dados.length retorna o tamanho do vetor.
    {
        conteudo += dados[i].tb02_cafe;
        conteudo2 += dados[i].tb02_lanchedia;
        conteudo3 += dados[i].tb02_almoco;
        conteudo4 += dados[i].tb02_lanchenoite;
    }

    document.getElementById("cafe1").innerHTML = conteudo;
    document.getElementById("lanche1").innerHTML = conteudo2;
    document.getElementById("almoco1").innerHTML = conteudo3;
    document.getElementById("lanchen1").innerHTML = conteudo4;
    }}}
```

De qualquer forma, obrigado à todos! ;)

Comment: pode crer, eu tinha entendido que podia não haver dados pra uma das refeições, não me liguei que você estava falando da data inteira, hehe

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia!

Primeiramente, te sugiro a utilizar alguma biblioteca Javascript como [Jquery](https://jquery.com/), por exemplo. Acredito que realmente vá facilitar teu trabalho no front-end e a maneira como tu vai tratar os dados.

O segundo ponto que na minha opinião que deve ser melhorado é a maneira como tu estás tratando os dados no back-end. Seria muito mais simples e correto tu retornar o resultado da tua consulta SQL e transformá-la para um formato json de verdade (não montando uma String), usando a função json_encode() que é nativa do PHP.

Respondendo a tua pergunta, vamos lá. No front-end, quando tu recebe os dados e manipula eles me parece um pouco confuso pois os lanches/cafés estão sendos todos concatenados em uma única variável que depois será exibida em um elemento HTML. Acredito que cada um destes valores deveriam ser atribuidos a uma lista, por exemplo, faria mais sentido. Deste modo, a única coisa que tu deveria realizar para atribuir o conteúdo desejado para as datas que não possuem valor seria algo do gênero:

```
conteudoX = (dados[i].tb02_dia_semana) ? dados[i].tb02_dia_semana: 'Data não informada';
```

Após a execução deste condicional a tua variável **conteudoX** possuirá o valor esperado e desta maneira tu poderás atribuir ao elemento que tu quiseres no HTML.

Espero ter ajudado :)

Abraços!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a própria query SQL para retornar "Não há registro!" como valor de um campo, caso ele seja nulo na `tb02`, usando `coalesce()`. Essa função retorna o primeiro valor não-nulo encontrado na lista:

```sql
SELECT 
    tb02_diasemana,
    coalesce(tb02_lanchedia,   'Não há registro!') as tb02_lanchedia,
    coalesce(tb02_almoco,      'Não há registro!') as tb02_almoco,
    coalesce(tb02_cafe,        'Não há registro!') as tb02_cafe,
    coalesce(tb02_lanchenoite, 'Não há registro!') as tb02_lanchenoite
FROM tb02_cardapiosem 
WHERE tb02_diasemana=' . $data
```

A vantagem é que o resto do seu código não muda. De quebra evita o uso de `select *`, que pode te causar dores de cabeça no futuro caso sejam adicionadas colunas novas na tabela.